# Return a custom error message in WCF http service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http, custom-errors

I'm just starting out in C# and am a little stuck on this.

I need to return a custom error message when a user doesn't have access to a particular resource.

Interface class for service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPatientDemographics
{
    [OperationContract]   
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetPatientDemographics/{strHospId}/{strView=mobile}",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "PatientDemographicsResultSet")]
    List<PatientDemographics> GetPatientDemographics(string strHospId, string strView);

    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(AccessError))]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Error")]
    AccessError ReturnAccessError();        
}

[DataContract]
public class AccessError
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Error { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Service class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode=AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class PatientDemographics : IPatientDemographics
{
    public List<PatientDemographics> GetPatientDemographics(string strHospId, string strView)
    {
        AuthenticationDAO authenticationDAO = new AuthenticationDAO();
        string userName = GetUserNameFromHeader();

        if (authenticationDAO.CheckPatientSealAccess(strHospId, userName, "-1", "N"))
        {
            PatientDAO patientDAO = new PatientDAO();
            patientDAO.AuditPatient(strHospId, userName);
            return patientDAO.GetPatientDemographics(strHospId);
        }
        else
        {
            AccessError serviceData = new AccessError();
            serviceData.Error = true;
            serviceData.Message = "User does not have access to patient record";
            throw new FaultException<AccessError>(serviceData, "User does not have access to patient record");
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, this just returns a null object if the user doesn't have access. I tried throwing a FaultException but had no luck. Ideally I want it to return in JSON format something like:

```
{
    error: "User does not have access to patient record"
}
```

Comment: This isn't a ".NET web service": it's WCF. You need to tag your questions more precise :D

Comment: Could you show the code used to throw the fault exception?

Comment: I've editted in the code I tried

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Channel Dispatcher to add error handler and define custom fault contract.

There is good article about Error handling in WCF 3.5. It is long way to describe what you need as I was penalised for posting URL. I would suggest you to look in code project for 
"WCF Error Handling and Fault Conversion". A good article written by Sasha Goldshtein.
Hope this helps.

Comment: You wouldn't be penalized for posting a link. If you explain a possible approach/idea and you add a link as reference is better than a conceptual link like the one provided in your answer :P

Comment: I have given approach recently and added url still I loose 3 points thanks.

Comment: This is sad. There're a lot of *dowvote* whor*s, but my impression is that SO works and you don't need to worry about downvoters forever...

Comment: I agree but I want to have gain 50 points to get comments going. hence my points quest. any way I'm not in any game. thanks for the sprit

Comment: It's a strong argument (the thing about the comments)